# Empty soap:body when calling a web service from windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-phone-8

I started from a WSDL file and I used the "Add Service Reference" capability to generate proxy classes. The server is Java/Axis.

I am using the following code:

```
MyServiceClient c = new MyServiceClient();
c.getVersionStringCompleted += new EventHandler<getVersionStringCompletedEventArgs>(MyCallBack);
var r = new getVersionStringRequest { };
c.getVersionStringAsync(r);
```

My Callback is really simple, just to verify at the beginning that the setup is OK.

```
static void MyCallBack(object sender, getVersionStringCompletedEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("result {0}", e.ToString());
}
```

The endpoint is taken from the WSDL.

The server responds that there is no Body in the request.

What is wrong with my code? I am running Visual Studio 2013.

What is the correct way to access the service?

I am not sure if it needed however I am adding my conf file here:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="MyServiceSoapBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://135.99.14.73:8081/axis/services/MyService"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServiceSoapBinding"
                contract="LoginReference.MyService" name="MyService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say the server responds that there is no body in the request? Does it return a fault with a 500 error code?

Comment: Also, FYI, the endpoint in the WSDL is meant only as a hint. It may not be the endpoint of the live service.

Comment: @JohnSaunders it returns 500 and the endpoint URI is the correct one

Comment: Does the webservice call work if you try it synchronously?

Comment: I don't have synchronous methods in the Reference.cs file

Comment: Is this a Silverlight or Windows Phone application?

Comment: It is a Windows Phone 8 app.

Comment: The error seems like it explains everything "no body in the request"... sounds like you're missing some value that you need to assign in `getVersionStringRequest`. Is this a publicly available web service?

Comment: The request does not have arguments. I added the new getVersionStringRequest { }; however no luck

Comment: Just captured the traffic and indeed the Body is empty, ie contains no main method

Comment: @cateof: please get into the habit of tagging your Windows Phone questions with the [wp8] tag. As you should by now know, there are aspects of Windows Phone development which are fairly unique to it. Like, the fact that you have no synchronous methods!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use synchronous methods:

```
ChannelFactory<LoginReference.MyService> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<LoginReference.MyService>("MyService");

// Create a channel.
LoginReference.MyService wcfClient1 = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
string s = wcfClient1.getVersionString();
Console.WriteLine(s);
((IClientChannel)wcfClient1).Close();
```

Do you have access to the service log? What does it say?

What does WCF test client tool say? Did you try to reach the service via Fiddler?